# Get Employees Achievements Final Mark Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem coming up with a SQL query to calculate the final achievement mark for an employee in any month, the final result should be calculated this:

> Sum(objective mark * objective weight) / all objectives count

And here is the structure of my tables:

> 1- Employees table:
> Id,
> Fullname

> 2- Objectives table:
> Id,
> Title,
> Weight

> 3- Achievements table:
> Id,
> Obj_id,
> Emp_id,
> Mark,
> Date (month-year)

I need the query to give a result like below:

> Fullname result date
> John     56     4-2021
> John     59     5-2021
> Henry    70     4-2021
> Henry    57     5-2021

I hope i made my question clear, thans for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `join` and `group by`:

```
select e.id, e.fullname,
       sum(a.mark * o.weight) / sum(o.weight),
       a.date
from employees e join
     achievements a
     on e.id = a.emp_id join
     objectives o
     on o.id = a.obj_id
group by e.id, e.fullname, a.date;
```